# What type of code do I use to let unlimited inputs?

Tags: c++, cin

```
#include <iostream>
int main {

    cin>>i;
    cout<<i;

}
```

How do I change the `cin` part so that it lets in any amount of inputs separated by a space?

Comment: Do you mean you want a string with spaces *in* it? Or do you want entries *separated* by spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
int num;
cout << "Enter numbers separated by a space" << endl;
do 
{
  cin >> num;
  /* process num
     or use array or std::vector to store num for later use
  */

}while (true);
```

This might answer your query.

Comment: You might want to define num. He didn't define the variable in his question.

Comment: Any way to fix the code? I used your code and modified it. But, the result of this code was:                                               Enter numbers separated by a space
1
1Enter numbers separated by a space
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()

{
 int num;
 do {
   cout<<"Enter numbers separated by a space"<<endl;
   cin >> num;
   cout << num;

 }
 while (true);

}

Comment: Also, I got an error when running it. I need the input to be exactly when I entered. ex. Input: 1 2 3; Output: 1 2 3

Comment: put this line "cout<<"Enter numbers separated by a space"<<endl;" out of the loop

Comment: I did that, but I still got an error. Is there any way to fix it so that it prints out exactly what I entered. ex. Input: 1 2 3; Output: 1 2 3

Answer (score 0):

`getline` *might* be what you're looking for. Example from [CPlusPlus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/):

```
// istream::getline example
#include <iostream>     // std::cin, std::cout

int main () {
  char name[256], title[256];

  std::cout << "Please, enter your name: ";
  std::cin.getline (name,256);

  std::cout << "Please, enter your favourite movie: ";
  std::cin.getline (title,256);

  std::cout << name << "'s favourite movie is " << title;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can this help me input unlimited numbers though? Also, what does the "std::" do?

Comment: Hmmm... Do you have an estimate of how many numbers you want to input? For starters, a computer can't store an infinite amount of numbers...

Comment: Using the `std::` thing allows you to avoid saying that you are using a namespace like `using namespace std`.

Comment: I am using this type for this question:                      Given a list of integer numbers. The last number is -999.
Write a program to print out the total sum of each even number. Example:
Input:
2 -100 0 27 33 51 20 -999
Output:
-78

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what works best for unlimited inputs.

The best one is:

```
while (true){
cin >> i;
}
```

However, it does not take in spaces.

The one for taking in everything including spaces is getline, as mentioned by Dejay above.
The last one, which is not as handy as while (true) but still works is the for (;;). It works pretty much like while (true) and does not recognize whitespace characters.

Ex.

```
for(;;){
cin >> i;
}
```